# What is the search_path for a given database and user?

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I can see the current `search_path` with:

```
show search_path ;
```

And I can set the `search_path` for the *current session* with:

```
set search_path = "$user", public, postgis;
```

As well, I can permanently set the `search_path` for a given *database* with:

```
alter database mydb set search_path = "$user", public, postgis ;
```

And I can permanently set the `search_path` for a given *role* (user) with:

```
alter role johnny set search_path = "$user", public, postgis ;
```

But I would like to know how to determine what the *database* and *role* settings are (with respect to `search_path`) prior to altering them?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can find configuration settings for roles and databases in the catalog table [`pg_db_role_setting`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-db-role-setting.html).

This query retrieves any settings for a given role or database:

```
SELECT r.rolname, d.datname, rs.setconfig
FROM   pg_db_role_setting rs
LEFT   JOIN pg_roles      r ON r.oid = rs.setrole
LEFT   JOIN pg_database   d ON d.oid = rs.setdatabase
WHERE  r.rolname = 'myrole' OR d.datname = 'mydb';
```

If nothing is set, the next lower instance determines the default state of the `search_path`, which is `postgresql.conf` in this case or command-line options at server start. Related:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

To **unset** *any* settings of a role or database - the `search_path` in this particular example:

```
ALTER ROLE myrole RESET search_path;
```

Or:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb RESET search_path;
```

Or:

```
ALTER ROLE myrole in DATABASE mydb RESET search_path;
```

**Never** manipulate data in the system catalog (`pg_catalog.*`) manually. Use DDL commands as instructed in the manual for [`ALTER ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html) and [`ALTER DATABASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdatabase.html).
Essentially, the `RESET` command deletes a row from `pg_db_role_setting` allowing the base setting to take effect again. I wouldn't call that convoluted.

Comment: Wow. I did not imagine it would be this convoluted. How would you *unset* a given *database* and *role* setting? After executing `alter role myrole set search_path = "$user", public, postgis ;` I noticed that `pg_roles.rolconfig` (corresponding to my role) got the value `{"search_path=\"$user\", public, postgis"}`. Also, `select * from pg_db_role_setting ;` now shows an additional row. And after executing `alter database mydb set search_path = "$user", public, postgis ;` I see a corresponding row in `select * from pg_db_role_setting ;` -- in the end, I am unsure of how to "undo" these changes.

Comment: @user664833: I added instructions to unset.

Comment: @user664833, Note that this only alters the _default_ `search_path` of your user; they will still be able to `SET search_path TO something, else;` / `SELECT set_config('search_path', 'something, else', false);`

Answer (score 12):

The permanent settings for both databases and roles are stored in the  [pg_db_role_settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-db-role-setting.html) system cluster-wide table.

Only settings passed to `ALTER USER` and `ALTER DATABASE` are present in this table. To get at the values that are configured aside from these commands:

- The value of the setting prior to any change, including at the cluster level (through the global configuration `postgresql.conf`) can be queried from the database with:

  ```
   SELECT boot_val FROM pg_settings WHERE name='search_path';
  ```
- The value of the setting prior to any change **within the session** (through the `SET` command) can be queried from the database with:

  ```
   SELECT reset_val FROM pg_settings WHERE name='search_path';
  ```
- When it's set a non-default value in `postgresql.conf`, it's not straightforward to obtain that value in SQL **independently of the current session**. `pg_settings.boot_val` won't do because it ignores changes in the configuration file, and `pg_settings.reset_val` won't either, because it's influenced by the database/user settings potentially set through `ALTER USER/ALTER DATABASE`. The simplest way for a DBA to get the value is to just look it up in `postgresql.conf`. Otherwise, see
  [Reset search_path to the global, cluster default](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145280) which covers this topic in detail.

Comment: Isn't `boot_val` actually the compiled-in factory default, not the setting in `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: @Erwin: yes. One might want to look at `reset_val` instead of `boot_val`.

Comment: Hmm, database or role settings overwrite the value in `reset_val`. I stumbled across this old question researching this recent one: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145280/reset-search-path-to-the-global-cluster-default

Comment: @Erwin: ISTM that getting the value from postgresql.conf is likely to be  an XY problem in most cases. Anyway, I edited the answer to link to the newer question and expand a bit.

Answer (score 9):

```
select * from pg_user;
```

True for postgres and Redshift. This seems too simple compared to the previous answers that depend on `pg_db_role_setting`, but the `useconfig` column will have a list of user configs including `search_path`, formatted as a list.

[pg_user Postgres documentation is here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-user.html)

To be more selective:

```
rs.db.batarang.com cooldb:cooldude =#> select usename
                                              , useconfig 
                                       from   pg_user
                                       where  usename = 'cooldude';
┌────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  usename   │                      useconfig                      │
├────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ cooldude   │ {"search_path=dirt, test, \"$user\", public, prod"} │
└────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

*I think this user table contains all users in the cluster, not just specific db -- but I didn't verify that.*

Comment: Role isn't exactly the same as user. ;)

Comment: Vic could you elaborate? The Postgres doc are succinct and seem to say that user and role are no longer distinct concepts, but I’m not a DBA and would love more input. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/user-manag.html

Comment: Any 'role' can act as a user, a group, or both. But a user' is implied to have one other distinction. Reviewing the catalog we see that the views pg_role and pg_user both reference table pg_authid, but with the predicate rolcanlogin for users. 'Users' can login to your database and generally 'roles' define sets of authorization that users inherit.

Comment: Hi Vic, I know this post is old but was hoping to get some help here. I am suing search path to set default schema for a particular role(group). I understand I can set at the user level, but since we have group of users, we created role and would like all of them to default to using certain schema. Role rds_inv is what is created and svc_inv is granted this role. So if I set the below, the permissions are not inherited to user svc_inv. I was wondering if you could help me? Works only when set to user and not to role.
alter ROLE rds_inv SET search_path to "flow"; > Does not work