# CREATE DATABASE ... WITH TEMPLATE seems to lose relations in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, copy

I'm trying to [Create a copy of a database in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876522/creating-a-copy-of-a-database-in-postgresql) per the SO answer from 2009, but running into problems.

In Postgres 9.3.9, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876522/creating-a-copy-of-a-database-in-postgresql/876565#876565) creates a database with **no relations** (the gcis db exists and has tables and data):

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE gcis_rollback WITH TEMPLATE gcis OWNER postgres;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \c gcis_rollback
You are now connected to database "gcis_rollback" as user "postgres".
gcis_rollback=# \d
No relations found.
```

I get the same using the commandline `createdb`:

```
~$ createdb -O postgres -T gcis gcis_rollback2
~$ psql gcis_rollback2
psql (9.3.9)
Type "help" for help.

gcis_rollback2=# \d
No relations found.
```

Why don't I see a full copy of this DB?

*Background* - This is a dev server, where I can take down the connections to make a copy.  What I want is just a local copy for ease of rollback purposes while developing/testing DB schema changes using the Perl framework [Module::Build::Database](http://search.cpan.org/~bduggan/Module-Build-Database-0.57/lib/Module/Build/Database.pm) to build a patch.

*Additional info*:

```
gcis=# \l+ gcis
                                               List of databases
 Name |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges | Size  | Tablespace | Description 
------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------
 gcis | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                   | 35 MB | pg_default | 


gcis=# \d
                        List of relations
    Schema     |             Name             |   Type   | Owner  
---------------+------------------------------+----------+--------
 gcis_metadata | _report_editor               | table    | ubuntu
...
(57 rows)
```

Comment: Discussion moved to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32701/discussion-between-randall-and-a-horse-with-no-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name for leading me to this answer.

The relations appear to be missing because Postgres does not copy the `search_path` to the new database.  If you explicitly look in the specific schema, all relations are there:

```
\dt <schema>.*
```

So, the `search_path` needs to be explicitly set on the new database:

```
ALTER DATABASE gcis_rollback2 SET SEARCH_PATH gcis_metadata, public
```

@Erwin Brandstetter also provides [more information on viewing the search_path](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56023/what-is-the-search-path-for-a-given-database-and-user/56035#56035) for roles/dbs.

Comment: Your answer helped me. I had a similar issue. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301145/dt-says-did-not-find-any-relations/301146#301146