# \dt says "Did not find any relations."

Tags: postgresql, psql

I've been using Postgres 14 successfully, but now I'm stumped.  I have a database and schema `abc` which has tables.

```
\c abc
\dt     -- shows tables
```

I made a new database/schema `xyz`, but I cannot see the tables I made:

```
\c xyc
\dt
Did not find any relations.
```

If I use PgAdmin4 I can see `xyz`'s tables.
If I use DbVisualizer I can see `xyz`'s tables.
But if I use `psql` all I get is `Did not find any relations.`
It doesn't seem to matter if I am user `postgres` or myself (also superuser) in `psql`.
I created those `xyz` tables in PgAdmin4. Was that a mistake?
I've tried changing the owner of all the objects in the database or schema `xyz`, but no matter what I try, I just can't "see" them if I'm using `psql`.

Not sure if this sheds any light:

```
xyz-# \conninfo
You are connected to database "xyz" as user "postgres" via socket in "/tmp" at port "5432".
xyz=# \l
                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 xyz       | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 abc       | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
```

Comment: Databases contain schemas in PostgreSQL, unlike MySQL where they are 2 names for the same object. You won’t be able to view one database’s schemas/tables/etc. while connected to another.

Comment: @dwhitemv But if I do \c xyz, doesn't that connect me to the xyz database and its schema? I've created databases in PostgreSQL before, this is the first time this happened to me.

Comment: Maybe the difference was before I used something like DbVisualizer to create databases and tables, and it must have been doing some magic for me, whereas when I used PgAdmin4 to create this latest database, somehow the magic was missing.

Comment: "*doesn't that connect me to the xyz database and its schema?*"  - it connects you to the _database_ which in turn can contain _many_ schemas. So "connect to its schema" isn't really a thing. Why MySQL calls a "database" is in reality a "schema" in the SQL standard (and Postgres).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question, but here are some observations.

- From the question, I suspect that the `abc` database had all of its tables created in the default `public` schema, while the `xyz` database has its tables created in the `xyz` schema. Since `public` is part of the default search path, `psql` could find `abc`s tables successfully while in `xyz` you had to modify `search_path`.
- I suggest reading [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html) on how databases, schemas, and tables fit together.
- `\c` does not connect to a *schema*, it connects to a *database*. This is an important distinction.
- `search_path` defines the order in which schemas are searched when accessing unqualified object names. Objects can always be *schema-qualified* (i.e, `xyz.table1` will find `table1` in schema `xyz` but `table1` by itself will use `search_path`)
- `\d` and similar commands can *discover* objects using `search_path`, but it does not necessarily mean undiscovered objects are *inaccessible*. As you found,  you can access objects using schema-qualified identifiers even if `\d` et. al. doesn't list them. Relevant quote from the `psql` manpage under Patterns (bold mine):

  > Whenever the pattern parameter is omitted completely, the \d commands display **all objects that are visible in the current schema search path** — this is equivalent to using `*` as the pattern. (An object is said to be visible if its containing schema is in the search path and no object of the same kind and name appears earlier in the search path. This is equivalent to the statement that the object can be referenced by name without explicit schema qualification.) To see all objects in the database regardless of visibility, use `*.*` as the pattern.
- `SET` commands are session-local and never saved.
- `ALTER DATABASE .. SET search_path` only affects new sessions, you would have to reconnect to see the updated path.

Answer (score 7):

I saw this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123240/create-database-with-template-seems-to-lose-relations-in-postgresql?rq=1) and it partially solved the problem I was having (*"The relations appear to be missing because Postgres does not copy the search_path to the new database"*).

That is, I can see the tables like this:

```
xyz= \dt xyz.*
```

but not like this:

```
xyz= \dt
```

I tried setting the search path, currently:

```
"$user", public
```

to:

```
public, xyz
```

which is the way the other one looks (the one that works), but the setting didn't stick.

**UPDATE**  This worked:

```
xyz=# set search_path to xyz,public;
SET
xyz=# show search_path;
 search_path 
-------------
 xyz, public
(1 row)

xyz=# \dt
       List of relations
 Schema |        Name        | Type  |  Owner  
--------+--------------------+-------+---------
 xyz    | aircraft           | table | myname
 xyz    | pilot_availability | table | myname
 xyz    | pilots             | table | myname
 xyz    | sorties            | table | myname
 ...    | ...                | table | myname
```

*Unfortunately*, it appears setting the `search_path` does not stick.  I have to set it every time I start `psql`, for this `xyz` database/schema.

But this seems to have made the setting stick:

```
alter database xyz set search_path = xyz, public;
```

Comment: Set it in your `~/.psqlrc` or similar.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, for the information regarding `xyz= \dt xyz.*`.