# After creating a table in postgres with psql, \dt gives "Did not find any relations"

Tags: postgresql, linux, psql, docker

I'm working with postgres14 in a docker container on a remote Rocky Linux VM. After a little bit of pain I managed to access the database from outside the container, at which point I wanted to create a test database and some test tables to see if everything goes well. Unfortunately it doesn't, and here are the steps I'm going through.

1. connect to postgres

   `psql -U username -h container_ip`
2. once I'm in, I want create the db

   `create database mydb`
3. now I try to create a table

   `\c mydb`

   `create table mytable`
4. trying to check if it's created
   `\dt`

   out: `Did not find any relations.`

Now I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865564/why-command-dt-gives-no-relations-found) as well as  [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301145/dt-says-did-not-find-any-relations), but since I'm not really a DBA or anything of a sort I'm having a hard time understanding how to apply these answers to my particular problem. I tried altering search_path as suggested in one of the answers on these two links, in particular setting it to a public schema for mydb, but that didn't work.

Does anyone have an answer?
Thank you very much!

Comment: This maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I managed to create a table by using create table test(id int);CREATE TABLE syntax, but I can't do anything else, like select * from test for example. If I end statements with semicolons, I'm getting Syntax error.