# Reset search_path to the global, cluster default

Tags: postgresql, configuration

Say I permanently alter my database's `search_path` like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE my_db SET search_path TO "$user",public,other_schema;
```

How can I reset it back to whatever the default that a pristine, unaltered database on this cluster would have?

This is usually `"$user",public`, but that can be changed from the [configuration file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html). Having a way to read the value of parameters that come from the configuration file would work (so I could build a dynamic query at worst), but I haven't had any luck finding anything of the sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Factory defaults

> How can I reset it back to whatever the default that a pristine,
> unaltered database on this cluster would have?

You can read `boot_val` from [`pg_settings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-settings.html), but that's actually the compiled-in factory default, not the setting in `postgresql.conf`.

```
SELECT boot_val
FROM   pg_settings
WHERE  name LIKE 'search_path';
```

#### You aren't overlooking the simple `RESET`?

To just *reset* the setting (remove it), you can simply:

```
ALTER DATABASE my_db RESET search_path;
```

But that doesn't necessarily give you what *"a pristine, unaltered database on this cluster would have"*. It just removes the custom setting for the database. There are *several* ways to set the search path:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

And it does not change the `search_path` of your *current* session. The effect (if any) is visible in your next session.

Related:

- [What is the search_path for a given database and user?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56023/what-is-the-search-path-for-a-given-database-and-user/56035#56035)

#### Connect to `template1`

You *could* get the current setting from a connection to `template1`, like [@Abelisto suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145280/reset-search-path-to-the-global-cluster-default#comment275619_145280). But you probably want to stay within your current session. You could use dblink for that:

```
SELECT * FROM dblink('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=template1 user=postgres password=you_wish'
                         , $$SELECT boot_val, source FROM pg_settings
                             WHERE name LIKE 'search_path'$$
                          ) AS t(search_path text, source text);

search_path    | source
---------------+---------
"$user",public | default
```

This has **a couple of challenges**:

- You need the additional module `dblink` installed. That's simple:
- [Persistent inserts in a UDF even if the function aborts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104994/persistent-inserts-in-a-udf-even-if-the-function-aborts/105186#105186)
- You need the privilege to connect to `template1`. And you need to supply the user password.
- Even in `template1` the setting might stem from settings to the role or database (or another instance) as well (even though they probably don't). So check the columns `source`. If it says *'default'*, you got it. If it says *'database'* or *'user'* you are back to square 1 ...

#### Read actual setting in `postgresql.conf`

.. using`pg_read_file()`, but this is also subject to some important **restrictions**. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE):

> Use of these functions is restricted to **superusers**.

And:

> Only files within the database **cluster directory and the `log_directory`** can be accessed.

Bold emphasis mine.
If your config files are somewhere else (like in default installations on Debian and friends) you would have to create a symbolic link in the file system in your data or log directory to your actual config file.

```
SELECT substring(txt, $$\nsearch_path\s*=\s*'([^']+)'$$) AS search_path
FROM   pg_read_file((SELECT setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'config_file')
                  , 0, 10000000) AS txt;  -- arbitrary 10 MB max.

search_path
------------
public
```

Note how I fetch the path to the config file dynamically with:

```
SELECT setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'config_file'
```

Then I use a regular expression with substring() to extract the setting:

```
\nsearch_path\s*=\s*'([^']+)'
```

That should work, I didn't spend much time to make the regexp bullet-proof, though. Might be fooled by a commented setting that matches first or something. You might want to test some more.

Finally, since Postgres 9.4, there is also the [**`ALTER SYSTEM`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html) command to override settings in a **`postgresql.auto.conf`** file. You'll have to check that, too.